# using cv.readImage() with stream in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv, stream, webcam

Im trying to build something like this
https://github.com/xenomuta/caraweb
Facedetection with OpenCV and nodejs.

Im using Ubuntu and Im already able to stream the pictures from my webcam.

So this is my .js for the webcam

```
var socket = io.connect();
var fps = 30;

socket.on('connect', function () {
    $('.serverStatus').text('Connected')
});
socket.on('connecting', function () {
    $('.serverStatus').text('Connecting')
});
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    $('.serverStatus').text('Disconnected')
});

var declinedCam = function(e) {
    alert('You have to enable the webcam');

};


window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);


var video = document.querySelector('video');

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }, declinedCam);
} else {
    alert('Your browser does not support the webcamcontrol');
}

video.addEventListener('play', function(e) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('frontendCanvas');

    var goByScale = (video.videoHeight >= video.videoWidth) ? 'Height':'Width';
    var scale = (300/ video['video'+goByScale]);

    canvas.width = video.videoWidth * scale;
    canvas.style.width = canvas.width + 'px';
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight * scale;
    canvas.style.height = canvas.height + 'px';

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    setInterval(function() {
        if(video.paused !== true){
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth*scale, video.videoHeight*scale);
            socket.emit('videoStream', canvas.toDataURL('image/webp'));

        }
    }, 1000 / fps)
}, false);
```

and the app.js

```
var express = require('express.io');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var backend = require('./routes/backend');
var cv = require('opencv');
var fs = require('fs');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


// connection setup
app.http().io();




app.io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('videoStream', function(data) {

            socket.broadcast.emit('sendVideo', data);
var buffer = new Buffer(data, 'base64');



});
})
```

When Im trying to detect the face in a picture, Im using something like this:

```
cv.readImage("/picture.png", function(err, im){});
```

But how can I use the data from the webcamstream to detect people in front of the cam?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit old, but it may help someone.

You don't have to encode your canvas images to dataURL, you can send the blob directly to the server. On your HTML (client side):

```
function processCanvas(){
    // You call processCanvas() only once, after that is socket `canvasModified` 
    // event who calls it everytime it gets refreshed (see below)   

    var cnv = document.getElementById("canvasOutput")

    cnv.toBlob(function(blb){
        socket.emit('canvasUpdated', blb);
    }, 'image/jpeg', 0.8);
}
```

Then, on your Node.js server:

```
let modifyCanvas = (canvasBlob) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cv.readImage(canvasBlob, function(err, im){
            // Here you can process and do whatever with your image (im)
            ...

            // Once done everything, you can pass it again to JS by doing
            let arraybuffer = im.toBuffer();
            resolve(arraybuffer);
        });
    });
}

socket.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('canvasUpdated', function(b){
        let buffer = Buffer.from(b);

        modifyCanvas(buffer).then((blb) => {
            try{
                socket.emit('canvasModified', blb);
            }catch(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And finally, again on your client side, you draw it on an image element (it's easier) when the event is emitted:

```
socket.on('canvasModified', function(blb){
    var b = new Blob([blb]);
    document.getElementById('imgModified').src = URL.createObjectURL(b);
    processCanvas();
});
```

If you want to draw it to a canvas, you can grab that image element and paint it to the canvas by doing something like:

```
var imageElement = document.getElementById("imgModified");
document.getElementById("canvasOutput").getContext('2d').drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0);
```

Hope it helps!